# Diagonalizability of matrix A

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Show that A is not diagonalizable in the form of $PDP^{-1}$ given eigenvalues.

In this question, A is $\begin{pmatrix} 54 & -220 & 26 & -66 \\ 12 & -50 & 6 & -15 \\ 86 & -352 & 45 & -108 \\ 40 & -160 & 20 & -50\end{pmatrix}$ and

D (or the eigenvalues) is 
$\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

I just need some hints to get going, is it really inevitable to have to calculate the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Must you show that $A$ is not diagonalisable, or that it is not of the form $PDP^{-1}$ for _the given_ $D$ and any invertible $P$, which is quite a different kettle of fish (even if it is not of that form, it could very well still be diagonalisable).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen probably the latter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: One basis-invariant quantity that is easy to compute is the trace.

Comment: Because I think the OP might not understand the terminology: the trace of $A$ doesn't equal the trace of $D$, therefore there is no matrix $P$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Comment: I feel so stupid for not noticing that....

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ has really the eigenvalues $-2,2,-1$ and $1$, then $A$ is diagonalizable !

Thus check, what are the eigenvalues of $A$.